# How do you create a SQL Server database with Perl?

Tags: sql-server, perl, sql-server-2008

I have a Perl script running on a Unix box in which one of its tasks is to create MySQL databases. I am now writing a Windows version to create Microsoft SQL Server databases and I cannot figure out what function/procedure to use to actually create the database.

I use the following statements to create a MySQL database in Unix:

```
my($drh) = DBI->install_driver("mysql");
$drh->func('createdb', $databaseName, $host, $username, $password, 'admin');
```

What is the equivalent to this for SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute the relevant "CREATE DATABASE" sql as with any other query. Obviously first you'll need to connect to another DB as a user with the relevant permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The `func` method. From the Perldoc:

> The func method can be used to call private non-standard and non-portable methods implemented by the driver. Note that the function name is given as the last argument.
>
> [...]
>
> See also install_method() in DBI::DBD for how you can avoid needing to use func() and gain direct access to driver-private methods.

Can you use the [install_method](http://search.cpan.org/%7Etimb/DBI-1.616/lib/DBI/DBD.pm#Using_install_method()_to_expose_driver-private_methods) to do what you want? It's a bit more portable?